# How to retrieve <fork>:<branch name> from github and use them in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, branch, git-fork

I have already installed the Github plugin in Jenkins

This is my scenario:

1. PR is created in github: john_doe_fork:john_do_branch
2. I want to retrieve john_doe_fork and john_do_branch from github each time a PR is created against our github repo so I can them in my deploy script.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have similar requirement. @Aziz were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're better off using a Jenkins plugins that was designed for this exact usecase, such as the [Github pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin)